# What is the meaning of such construction in powershell

Tags: powershell

Very newbie question. Found such workflow in MS Exchange script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param ()
begin {
    $scriptBlock = {
        function foo {
            # some code
        }
        foo
    }
}
process {
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
}
```

as i understand it is for running this script on remote hosts, but how? or there are any other reasons for such invoke-comand as a single call in process part? Or please sugest keywords to find more about this?

Here is full script: [aka.ms/ResetScanEngineVersion](https://aka.ms/ResetScanEngineVersion)

Comment: This would have a logical explanation if the outer function was pipeline compatible but aside from that, there doesn't seem to be a real need for this, could be all as well in the end block

Comment: Please share (or link to) the full script.

Comment: No, there were no outer functions. Here is full example: https://aka.ms/ResetScanEngineVersion

Comment: The only immediate motivation for this sort of loopback remoting I can think of is to ensure elevated execution - WinRM loopback sessions require local admin privileges on Windows 10 since 19H1